# Separate clipboard for particular application

Tags: clipboard, sandbox

Is it possible, on Debian with Klipper running, to have a separate "clipboard stack" for a particular application?

I'd like the text that I copy in application Y not to be shared with all the other applications running.

All the solutions mentioned at [this other answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/56703) seems like overkill.